# problem to handle more than 1 work at the same time in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-redux

in my react todo app I have some tasks in three container "Todo, Doing, Done"
in this app if the checkbox of a task checked it should shows at the first of Done container and if the checkbox of a task unchecked it should shows at the first of Todo container.

now everything works well but if I checked or unchecked more than one task at the same time just the last task will change. how should I fix it?

**Body Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import TodoContainer from './TodoContainer'

export default function Body() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

    const handleDeleteTask = (taskIndex, section) => {
    const updatedTodos = { ...todos };
    updatedTodos[section] = updatedTodos[section].filter((_, index) => index !== taskIndex);
    setTodos(updatedTodos)
};

const handleAddTask = (newTask, section) => {
    const updatedTodos = { ...todos };
    updatedTodos[section] = [newTask, ...todos[section]];
    setTodos(updatedTodos)
};

useEffect(() => {
    const hasInitialDataLS = localStorage.getItem("hasInitialDataLS");
    if (!hasInitialDataLS) {
        // Pre-save initial information
        const preSavedData = {
            todo: [
                { title: 'Start with meditation, exercise & breakfast for a productive day', check: 0 },
                { title: 'Read to learn something new every day', check: 0 },
                { title: 'Learn something fresh & relevant', check: 0 }
            ],
            doing: [
                { title: 'Engage & question in meetings', check: 0 },
                { title: 'Use time-blocking for effective days', check: 0 }
            ],
            done: [
                { title: 'Use time-blocking for effective days', check: 1 },
                { title: 'Congratulate yourself for incorporating healthier habits into your lifestyle, like regular exercise or mindful eating', check: 1 }
            ]
        };
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(preSavedData));
        localStorage.setItem("hasInitialDataLS", "true");
        setTodos(preSavedData);
    } else {
        const storeTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
        if (storeTodos) {
            setTodos(JSON.parse(storeTodos));
        }
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // Update localStorage whenever todos state changes
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]); // This effect runs whenever todos change

return (
    <div className="body">
        <TodoContainer
            className="todo"
            title="Todo"
            requirementTasks={todos.todo}
            onDeleteTask={(taskIndex) => handleDeleteTask(taskIndex, 'todo')}
            setTodos={setTodos}
            todos={todos}
            onAddTask={(newTask) => handleAddTask(newTask, 'todo')}
        />
        <TodoContainer
            className="doing"
            title="Doing "
            requirementTasks={todos.doing}
            onDeleteTask={(taskIndex) => handleDeleteTask(taskIndex, 'doing')}
            setTodos={setTodos}
            todos={todos}
            onAddTask={(newTask) => handleAddTask(newTask, 'doing')}
        />
        <TodoContainer
            className="done"
            title="Done "
            requirementTasks={todos.done}
            onDeleteTask={(taskIndex) => handleDeleteTask(taskIndex, 'done')}
            setTodos={setTodos}
            todos={todos}
        />
    </div>
)
}
```

**Todo Container Component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Task from './Task'
import Button from './Button';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from './constants';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default function TodoContainer({
className,
title,
requirementTasks,
onDeleteTask,
setTodos,
todos,
onAddTask,
}) {
const [isDraggingOver, setIsDraggingOver] = useState(false);
const ref = useRef();

const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.TASK,
    drop: (item) => {
        const { index: originalIndex, section: originalSection } = item;
        const newSection = className; // The current section where the drop occurred
        if (originalSection !== newSection) {
            // Handle the task movement from originalSection to newSection
            const updatedOriginalTasks = [...todos[originalSection]];
            const updatedNewTasks = [...todos[newSection]];
            const taskToMove = updatedOriginalTasks.splice(originalIndex, 1)[0];
            if (className === 'done') {
                taskToMove.check = 1;
            } else {
                taskToMove.check = 0; // Reset check status when moving tasks
            }
            updatedNewTasks.unshift(taskToMove);

            setTodos((prevTodos) => ({
                ...prevTodos,
                [originalSection]: updatedOriginalTasks,
                [newSection]: updatedNewTasks,
            }));
        }
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
});

useEffect(() => {
    drop(ref); // Pass the ref of the container to the drop function

    const handleDragOver = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsDraggingOver(true);
    };

    const handleDragLeave = () => {
        setIsDraggingOver(false);
    };

    ref.current.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
    ref.current.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave);

    return () => {
        ref.current.removeEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
        ref.current.removeEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave);
    };
}, [drop]);

const tasks = requirementTasks || [];

return (
    <div className={`${className} todo-container  ${isDraggingOver ? "dragging-over" : ""}`} ref={ref}>
        <div className="todo-header">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <small>{tasks.length} Tasks</small>
        </div>

        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
            <div className="tasks" key={uuidv4()}>
                <Task
                    context={task.title}
                    check={task.check}
                    handleDeleteTask={() => onDeleteTask(index)}
                    index={index}
                    setTodos={setTodos}
                    todos={todos}
                    requirementTasks={requirementTasks}
                    onAddTask={onAddTask}
                    section={className} />
            </div>
        ))}
        {className === 'done' ? '' : <Button
            type='add'
            onClickFun={() => { onAddTask({ title: '', check: 0 }); }} />}
    </div>
)
}
```

**Task Compoennt**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from './constants';
import Button from './Button';

export default function Task({
context,
check,
handleDeleteTask,
index,
setTodos,
todos,
requirementTasks,
section,
}) {
const [, drag] = useDrag({
    type: ItemTypes.TASK,
    item: { index, section },
});

const [isEditingTitle, setIsEditingTitle] = useState(false);
const [taskCheck, setTaskCheck] = useState([])
const [text, setText] = useState(context);
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(check);

const handleTitleClick = () => {
    setIsEditingTitle(true);
};

const handleTextChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
};

const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsEditingTitle(false);

    const updatedTasks = [...requirementTasks];
    updatedTasks[index].title = text;
    setTodos({
        ...todos,
        [section]: updatedTasks,
    });
};

const timeoutRef = useRef(null);

const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
    setIsChecked((prevIsChecked) => !prevIsChecked);
    const taskToMove = { ...requirementTasks[index] };
    setTaskCheck(taskToMove.check)
    taskToMove.check = isChecked ? 0 : 1;

    if (timeoutRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    const newTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (taskCheck !== taskToMove.check) {
            const updatedSectionTasks = [...todos[section]];
            const updatedTargetTasks = isChecked ? [...todos.todo] : [...todos.done];

            updatedSectionTasks.splice(index, 1);
            updatedTargetTasks.unshift(taskToMove);

            setTodos({
                ...todos,
                [section]: updatedSectionTasks,
                [isChecked ? 'todo' : 'done']: updatedTargetTasks,
            });
        }
    }, 3000);

    timeoutRef.current = newTimeout; // Store the reference to the new timeout
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditingTitle && inputRef.current) {
        const input = inputRef.current;
        input.focus();
    }
}, [isEditingTitle]);

return (
    <div className={`task ${isEditingTitle ? '' : 'dis-flex'}`} ref={drag}>
        <label className="checkbox-container">
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
            />
            <span className={`checkmark ${isChecked ? 'checked' : ''}`}></span>
        </label>
        {isEditingTitle ? (
            <input
                ref={inputRef}
                value={text}
                onChange={handleTextChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                className="task-input"
            />
        ) : (
            <span
                onClick={handleTitleClick}
                className={`${isChecked ? 'text-decoration' : ''}`}
            >
                {text ? text : <input placeholder="new Task" className="new-task" />}
            </span>
        )}
        <Button
            type="delete"
            onClickFun={() => {
                handleDeleteTask(index);
            }}
        />
    </div>
);
}
```